# How to extract a single value from a series?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to create a series in which every value is normalized to the value of a particular element in the series, for example the latest value.

If you try syntax that would work in other common languages:

```
normalized_close = close / close[0]
```

the result will be an array of 1's because Pine is taking the ratio between the closing price relative to the closing price of the same bar (0 offset).  I want to get the ratio between the closing price in each bar relative to the single closing price of the latest bar. In pseudocode, it would look something like this.

```
latest_close = get_value_at_index(close, 0)
normalized_close = close / latest_close
```

Where the function `get_value_at_index(series, index)` is the function I can't seem to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `array`, set its values with a `for` loop and get the value at any index you want.

Here is an example with seeting an index with 1000 `close` prices and getting the result from 3 bars ago:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

// create new array
normalized_close_array = array.new_float(1000)

// append to that array
for i=1 to array.size(normalized_close_array) - 1
    array.set(normalized_close_array, i, close[i] / close)

// get the value at any index you want
value_we_want = array.get(normalized_close_array, 3)

plot(value_we_want)
```

Comment: I just tried this script, and value_we_want is exactly equal to close[3]/close.  The array is an array of series, kind of like a 2D array.  This is a cool feature that I didn't know about, but not quite what I'm looking for.  I just want a single float value that is equal to the value of the last closing price, which I can use to divide into the entire series.